# How to determine the clock resolution of a system?

Tags: java, system, clock

In scanning the docs for information about the resolution of `System.nanoTime()`, I found that

> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily
>   nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no
>   guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as
>   that of currentTimeMillis().

Jumping to `currentTimeMillis()`, I found

> Note that while the unit of time of the return value is a millisecond,
>   the granularity of the value depends on the underlying operating
>   system and may be larger.

That being said, how can I determine the clock resolution of my computer? Is it determined by the version of the OS, by the processor, or by something else?

Comment: It's determined by basically everything in between whatever the machine uses for keeping time and whatever uses those values. It's almost never determined by the processor, even on embedded systems--although the processor and how it interacts with the underlying timing mechanism *may* matter.

Comment: You may use RTLinux and check how to design, develop and running a real-time application on Linux for example http://xenomai.org/building-applications-with-xenomai-3-x/